# Android, create "non visible" .apk

Tags: android, android-intent, plugins

I am working on an Android framework which is composed by a main .apk that executes in foreground and a set of "plug-ins" which are .apk that can be downloaded and installed into the device silently.
The main purpose of this architecture is to have only 1 application running and being visible to the user and a set of plugins executed by the main application but that cannot be executed directly.

So far I found that one way to discover the available packages installed on my device is the following code:

```
packageManager = getPackageManager();
applications = new ArrayList<>();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
List<ResolveInfo> availableActivities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,0);
```

But this code retrieves all the packages that have a CATEGORY_LAUNCHER exposed.
My question is the following:

- Can I create an apk that when installed is not visible by the user? So it does not give the possibility to be launched as stand-alone?
- If I create a custom INTENT, how can I make the main application aware of a new package that is grouped into the new intent, has been installed in the system? A sort of trigger, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> that can be downloaded and installed into the device silently

That is not possible, except perhaps on a rooted device or via a special system app. Otherwise, the user will be involved in the installation of your plugins.

> Can I create an apk that when installed is not visible by the user? So it does not give the possibility to be launched as stand-alone?

You can have an app that does not have an activity with a `LAUNCHER` `<intent-filter>`, if that is what you mean. The user will still see your plugin in the list of installed applications and other places in Settings.

You will also need to use an explicit `Intent` (one that has the component set) when working with this plugin, to move it out of the stopped state. Until you talk to some component of the app using an explicit `Intent`, nothing in the plugin will run (e.g., manifest-registered receivers).

> If I create a custom INTENT, how can I make the main application aware of a new package that is grouped into the new intent, has been installed in the system?

That is not a valid English sentence. I am going to interpret it as meaning:

> How can I find out when the user installs a plugin?

You can watch for [`ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED` broadcasts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED) to find out when new apps are installed. At that point, you can determine if the newly-installed app is a plugin of yours, by one means or another.

Comment: Apologize for my english. Perfect answer, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the following from the Manifest file for required Activity.

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```